# How to make a exponential fade that doesn't start from 0 db

Tags: pro-tools, fader

How can I achieve a exponential fade that doesn't start from 0 db in pro tools?
the curve should look something like this [image]

Comment: What do you mean by exponential fade? Like... a fade out effect? Pretty much every audio editing program has fade out built in. (e.g. Audacity, Wavepad, etc.)

Comment: I don't use PT, but envelope should be the tool to accomplish this.